# Including prefill option in angular auth0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, auth0

I am using Auth0 for one of my projects and am stuck up with providing pre-fill options in the sign in form. 
Based on examples given on official Auth0 website, I used the following ways of including Auth0 in my Angular 1.5 application. I have only included the code where I tried to add the pre-filled email.

```
auth.signin({
  dict: {
    signin: {
      prefill: {
        email: "sameeksha.kumari@roames.com.au"
      }
    }
  },
  prefill: {
    email: "sameeksha.kumari@roames.com.au"
  }
});
```

And to my repeated disappointment, I keep on failing with prefilling the sign in form with email value when using it using angular.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe your issue may be related to the version of [lock](https://github.com/auth0/lock) you are using. Can you confirm whether you are using Lock 9+ or Lock 10+ ?

Lock 9+ was frequently used together with auth0-angular-4.js and angularjs 1.5. Running a quick `grep` across the Lock 9 source code base I found no matches for `prefill` (unlike same search against Lock 10 source code base).

Check this [example](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs-sample/blob/master/01-Login/index.html) that is using Lock 10+ with Angularjs 1.5.5 and auth0-7.0.3.min.js. Should give you a sample from which you can then customise to your own app - and now you have Lock 10 the prefill should be available.

Comment: You are right. I tried to use lock 10 at cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.0/lock.js with angular-auth0-5 at http://cdn.auth0.com/w2/auth0-angular-5.js. But they do not work together and prehash function is not found in the lock library by Auth0 and execution stops. Any workaround? I found this thread for same issue https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular/issues/104, but calling init says that set options need to be used before calling init and I could not go further.

Comment: You may like to work on this plunk  https://plnkr.co/edit/EJpBJAdeVjXDvmhE5Nqr?p=preview which shows error saying that parseOptions cannot be read from the library.

Comment: @SameekshaKumari - see updated answer with reference to a working angular 1x sample that uses Lock10 instead of Lock9

Comment: @SameekshaKumari - if you agree with my answer, please could you mark it correct - ie. Lock 9 does not support prefill attribute, Lock 10 does. :)